# Accessing ASP.NET Application Start Event without Application's original source code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm tasked with developing inside of a web portal which was developed by a 3rd party and for which I don't have the code behind file for Global.asax.cs.

I need to be able to be able to place code inside of the application start event though ... for example mapping routes for MVC and WebApi is the most critical thing I need to be  able to do right now. But since the 3rd party didn't provide the code behind, is there some other way I can get a hook into the Application Start event for this application?

Or was this lack of access intended as a "feature" to prevent client developers from running code inside application-level events?

Comment: You may be able to de-compile the existing `Global` class and re-compile it with your added code.  I think a more important issue here is that once you start tinkering with unsupported features of this 3rd party tool then you likely invalidate any support offered by that 3rd party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the global asax file, one simply refers to a class for an application.

You could replace this classname with your class that derives from this class ( if possible)

or try to call the event handlers inside this class yourself from your event handlers...

Comment: I think in order for me to derive from their class I'd need to provide Application_Start as an override so that the base class version of the method would get called still. However, their Application_Start is not marked virtual or "overrides" so I would have to use "new" on my Application_Start. That would block their code from executing.

Comment: I just noticed your second suggestion. I should be able to inherit, use new keywords on the events, and do base.Application_Start(sender, e) inside the events.